# QItemDelegate стили шрифта

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, делегаты

Есть класс `ItemDateFormat(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate)`, в нем переопределяю один метод `paint(self, painter, opt, index)`, так же есть табличное представление в столбец 'дата' которого устанавливаю делегат.
Для упрощения сортировки по полю 'дата', дата всегда в формате вида `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f`, что не читабельно из-за чего и прибегаю к помощи делегата.
При обработке данных требуется выделять текст и фон строк. Не могу понять как перенести в делегат оформление текста(курсив/цвет). Пните в нужном направлении.

```
import datetime
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class MessagesWindow(QtWidgets.QTableView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QTableView.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setModel(ModelMessages())
        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, ItemDateFormat())
        self.setShowGrid(True)

class ModelMessages(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QStandardItemModel.__init__(self, parent)
        for i in range(3):
            self.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem('2018-11-25 11:15:06.0001'), QtGui.QStandardItem(str(i)*3)])
            for col in range(0, self.columnCount()):
                if i == 0:
                    self.item(self.rowCount() - 1, col).setBackground(QtGui.QColor('#d7efe6'),)
                elif i == 1:
                    self.item(self.rowCount() - 1, col).setFont(QtGui.QFont(
                        QtWidgets.QApplication.font().family(), italic=True))
                elif i == 2:
                    self.item(self.rowCount() - 1, col).setData(
                        QtGui.QColor('#00159A'), QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole)

class ItemDateFormat(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate):

    def paint(self, painter, opt, index):
        self.drawBackground(painter, opt, index)
        self.drawFocus(painter, opt, opt.rect)
        try:
            opt.text = '{0:%d %b %H:%M}'.format(datetime.datetime.strptime(index.model().data(index), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
        except TypeError:
            opt.text = ""
        QtWidgets.QApplication.style().drawControl(
            QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, opt, painter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MessagesWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно минимальный пример в вопрос? Чтобы можно было запустить и проверить, а то этот делегат еще нужно встроить куда-то, это куда-то заполнить чем-то и т.д. :)

Comment: @gil9red изменил, добавил код на примере оформления курсивом.

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы делегат сам определял каким цветом (с курсивом) нужно рисовать, а не чтобы руками указывать, как вы сделали на примере курсива?

Comment: @gil9red именно, чтобы брал стили с ячейки в которую установлен.

Comment: @gil9red неверно выразился, установка оформления должна работать как указано в примере.

Comment: Ну, я основываясь на этом `Не могу понять как перенести в делегат оформление текста(курсив/цвет)` сделал пример. А `При обработке данных требуется выделять текст и фон строк.` у вас и так прекрасно работало и без делегата, поэтому объясните подробнее, лучше в вопросе, что вы хотите :)

Comment: Я правильно понял, что делегат должен сам закрасить ячейки в зависимости от текущей строки у ячейки? Вручную стиль для тех ячеек мы не указываем в модели?

Comment: Или нужно те закрасить, у которых дата парсится? Или делегат немного неправильно красит и вы хотите это исправить?

Answer (score 2):

У [QItemDelegate.paint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html#paint) есть аргумент `opt` с типом [QStyleOptionViewItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QStyleOptionViewItem.html).

В `opt` есть набор полей, измените нужные вам, чтобы был эффект:

```
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class MessagesWindow(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setModel(ModelMessages())
        self.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, ItemDateFormat())
        self.setShowGrid(True)

class ModelMessages(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem('2018-11-25 11:15:06.0001'), QtGui.QStandardItem('111')])
        self.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem('2018-11-25 11:15:06.0001'), QtGui.QStandardItem('111')])
        self.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem('2018-11-25 11:15:06.0001'), QtGui.QStandardItem('111')])

class ItemDateFormat(QtWidgets.QItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, opt: QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem, index):
        self.drawBackground(painter, opt, index)
        self.drawFocus(painter, opt, opt.rect)
        try:
            opt.text = '{0:%d %b %H:%M}'.format(datetime.strptime(index.model().data(index), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
        except TypeError:
            pass

        opt.font.setItalic(True)
        opt.backgroundBrush = QtCore.Qt.yellow

        QtWidgets.QApplication.style().drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, opt, painter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MessagesWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPD.**

Подумал, что использование делегата для изменения показываемого текста немного круто и предлагаю это сделать через саму модель.

У моделей есть `data` - этот метод возвращает данные, которые будут `view` переданы.

А значит мы можем вернуть те данные, которые захотим:

```
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class MessagesWindow(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setModel(ModelMessages())
        self.setShowGrid(True)

class ModelMessages(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        for i in range(3):
            self.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem('2018-11-25 11:15:06.0001'), QtGui.QStandardItem(str(i)*3)])

            for col in range(0, self.columnCount()):
                if i == 0:
                    self.item(self.rowCount() - 1, col).setBackground(QtGui.QColor('#d7efe6'))
                elif i == 1:
                    self.item(self.rowCount() - 1, col).setFont(QtGui.QFont(
                        QtWidgets.QApplication.font().family(), italic=True))
                elif i == 2:
                    self.item(self.rowCount() - 1, col).setData(QtGui.QColor('#00159A'), QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole)

    def data(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            try:
                text = self.itemFromIndex(index).text()
                dt = datetime.strptime(text, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                return '{0:%d %b %H:%M}'.format(dt)

            except:
                pass

        return super().data(index, role)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MessagesWindow()
    w.resize(300, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: неверно выразился, голова уже пухнет, менять я должен стили каждый раз как меняются данные в модели. С цветом фона проблем нет, проблема только с цветом текста, курсивом и полужирным выделением. Пока вижу вариант перегружать __init__ делегата и передавать при установке в представлении ссылку на модель, для перехвата нужных параметров, на основе которых и буду менять оформление, но это выглядит слишком нагруженно.

Comment: @Виктор, упростите вашу задачу до конкретного общего случая. А то у меня голова пухнуть будет, если буду по вашим мыслям понимать вашу задачу :)

Comment: упростил, написав конкретный случай. :) Внес изменения в представленный пример, добавив три условия, по которым и требуется менять оформление строк через: 
- замену цвета фона, с ним проблеем нет;
- через курсив или цвет текста, с которыми не придумал как грамотно поступить.

Comment: Отличное решение! Спасибо огромное! :)

Comment: @Виктор, о, рад что вам понравилось решение, тогда отметьте и примите мой ответ :)